# Any best way to create kibana automated snapshot to GCP storage as i am using an older version of Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

Any best way to create a kibana automated snapshot to GCP storage as I am using an older version of Kibana 7.7.1, Also I do not have any automated backup currently.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Kibana has Snapshot lifecycle management(SLM) that helps you do this. You have to run the [Kibana with basic license](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana)

Here is a [tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/snapshot-restore-tutorial.html), you could also directly use the [SLM API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-snapshot-lifecycle-management.html) to create and automate this process along with [Index-lifecycle management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ilm-wait-for-snapshot.html).

[image: Snapshot Lifecycle Management]